# Express Middleware not detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

my app can't seem to detect reference to an external middleware function.

Here is the index.js

./index.js

```
// ...................................................................................................................................
// dependencies
// ...................................................................................................................................
const Express = require('express');
const genres = require('./routes/genres'); // external routers to handle classifications of routes
const logger = require('./logger/logger'); // custome middleware

// ...................................................................................................................................
// instantiations
// ...................................................................................................................................
app = Express();

// ...................................................................................................................................
// Install middleware functions

// - These functions intercept the request response cycle
// - app.use to integrate existing functions or create custom ones
// - They're called in sequence of being defined

// ...................................................................................................................................

// built-in express middleware including custom user defined functions
app.use(Express.json()); // parse body of request object to json if detected

// custom middleware **I don't see a console.log()
app.use(logger);

// reference external routers
app.use('/api/genres', genres);
```

And here is the customer middleware function in logger/logger.js

./logger/logger.js

```
// custom middleware function to logg information
function log(req, res, next) {

    // prove access
    console.log('Logger middleware accessed...');

    next(); // pass control to the next middleware function
}

// export functions
module.exports = log;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Could you post what is the error log and also please could you post the genres route? Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out, very embarrassed that I posted this question actually. Thanks for your time Andres 

Comment: You are welcome